# The Error Argument 3 missing or nil : Script Troubleshooting

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

So idk nothing about scripting and I am making a tycoon from a tut and I need help with Argument 3 missing or nil here is the code

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

local Player = Players.LocalPlayer

local PlayerGui = Player:WaitForChild("PlayerGui")

local Remotes = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Remotes")

local Rng = Random.new()

local function AnimateBuild(Model)
    for _, v in Model:GetDescendants() do
        if v:IsA("BasePart") or v:IsA("UnionOperation") then
            local OriginalCFrame = v.CFrame
            local OriginalSize = v.Size
            local OriginalTransparency = v.Transparency
            
            local PositionOffset = Vector3.new(Rng:NextNumber(-2, 2), Rng:NextNumber(-2, 2))
            local RotationOffset = CFrame.Angles(Rng:NextNumber(-3, 3), Rng:NextNumber(-3, 3))
            v.CFrame = v.CFrame * CFrame.new(PositionOffset) * RotationOffset
            v.Transparancy = 1 
            
            TweenService:Create(v, TweenInfo.new(1, Enum.EasingStyle.Exponential, Enum.EasingDirection.Out), {CFrame = OriginalCFrame}):Play()
            TweenService:Create(v, TweenInfo.new(0.25, Enum.EasingStyle.Quart, Enum.EasingDirection.Out), {Transparency = OriginalTransparency}):Play()
            
        end
    end
end

Remotes:WaitForChild("BuildAnimation").OnClientEvent:Connect(function(Model)
    print("CALLED ANIMATION")
    AnimateBuild(Model)
end)
```

i have not tyyend enything idk what to do

Answer (score 0):

Both [`Vector3.new`](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/datatypes/Vector3#new) and [`CFrame.Angles`](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/datatypes/CFrame#Angles) expect *three* (3) [number](https://create.roblox.com/docs/luau/numbers) arguments. You only provide *two* (2) numbers to each:

```
local PositionOffset = Vector3.new(Rng:NextNumber(-2, 2), Rng:NextNumber(-2, 2))
local RotationOffset = CFrame.Angles(Rng:NextNumber(-3, 3), Rng:NextNumber(-3, 3))
```